# Liquibase checksum validation failed

Tags: liquibase

I am using `Liquibase (3.5.1)` in a Springboot application. I am using SQL based change log files. Adding new change-set ended up showing the check-sum validation error for the previous change-set.

Initial changelog file -

```
--liquibase formatted sql
--changeset tanmoy:1
create table serviceInstances (
    serviceId varchar(60),
    orgId  varchar(60),
    spaceId varchar(60),
    primary key (serviceId,orgId)
);
```

When added a new changeset like this -

```
--changeset tanmoy:2
create table serviceBindings (
    bindingId varchar(30) primary key,
    serviceId varchar(30),
    appId varchar(30),
    timeStamp BIGINT
);
```

the migration failed with this error logs -

```
Caused by: liquibase.exception.ValidationFailedException: Validation Failed:
     1 change sets check sum
          classpath:/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.sql::1::tanmoy was: 7:d15516f48de6531d1727cca8c56ec95a but is now: 7:3c7718f34f78701e0d2cadbf8278c1fa

    at liquibase.changelog.DatabaseChangeLog.validate(DatabaseChangeLog.java:266) ~[liquibase-core-3.5.1.jar:na]
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:210) ~[liquibase-core-3.5.1.jar:na]
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:192) ~[liquibase-core-3.5.1.jar:na]
    at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.performUpdate(SpringLiquibase.java:434) ~[liquibase-core-3.5.1.jar:na]
    at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(SpringLiquibase.java:391) ~[liquibase-core-3.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
```

Do not understand why the  check-sum of the previous change-set is changed and not validated. Is it because I have added a new change-set to the change log file? If it is then how do I add new change set ?

Comment: As far as you added a new changeset tag, even if is in the same .xml file should works correctly

Comment: Maybe you need to put every SQL change in a single file? And include every SQL change in a master xml changelog file. Right now it seems you have one file `db.changelog-master.sql` where the SQLs are inserted directly. I am not sure how the checksum is calculated when you use raw SQL files. It might be that the whole file is included in the checksum calculation. Then you'd definitively have to open up new files once the changeset are ran.

Comment: Your expectation is correct, the first changeset checksum should be intact. We use multiple changesets per single plain sql file and it works as expected. Please doublecheck: 1) the first changeset hasn't really changed. Whitespace changes are often a culprit, but current mercifully liquibase excludes them from the checksum calculation. 2) Double-check that you start the second changeset correctly. At times we would make a mistake there so that liquibase would think it is a part of the previous changeset with consequent checksum change.

Comment: @MykolaGurov do you know if line endings (EOL) or file endings (EOF) are taken into account when Liquibase calculates the checksum?

Answer (score 1):

On the level of the process, all the process is done `incrementally`. For example, when we create a table and want to make a change to the table, we give you a new incremental number. With this number, we determine the `changes` that we make in the one we create. It's like you're adding something new to your question. Therefore, you need to increase the `id` in your `liquibase.xml` file. If you have made changes to your present chart, do so as follows.

```
<changeSet id="73" author="fcelik">
    <comment>This change adds to customer_order table.</comment>
    <addColumn tableName="customer_order">
        <column name="owner_id" type="BIGINT">
            <constraints nullable="false"/>     
        </column>  
    </addColumn>
</changeSet>
```

Your file must be an unmatched value for your `liquabase.xml`. What you want to do between (usually the incremental path is tracked.) to create a file. For example, I have added a new column to the `customer_order` table here. Please note that `<addColumn>` when you use the tag.